# How to configure istio-proxy to log traceId?

Tags: istio, jaeger

I am using istio with version 1.3.5. Is there any configuration to be set to allow istio-proxy to log traceId? I am using jaeger tracing (wit zipkin protocol) being enabled. There is one thing I want to accomplish by having traceId logging:
- log correlation in multiple services upstream. Basically I can filter all logs by certain traceId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to envoy proxy documentation for envoy [`v1.12.0`](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.12.0/intro/arch_overview/observability/tracing.html?highlight=traceid#trace-context-propagation) used by istio `1.3`:

> ### Trace context propagation
>
> Envoy provides the capability for reporting tracing information regarding communications between services in the mesh. However, to be able to correlate the pieces of tracing information generated by the various proxies within a call flow, the services must propagate certain trace context between the inbound and outbound requests.
>
> Whichever tracing provider is being used, the service should propagate the  [x-request-id](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#config-http-conn-man-headers-x-request-id)  to enable logging across the invoked services to be correlated.
>
> The tracing providers also require additional context, to enable the parent/child relationships between the spans (logical units of work) to be understood. This can be achieved by using the LightStep (via OpenTracing API) or Zipkin tracer directly within the service itself, to extract the trace context from the inbound request and inject it into any subsequent outbound requests. This approach would also enable the service to create additional spans, describing work being done internally within the service, that may be useful when examining the end-to-end trace.
>
> Alternatively the trace context can be manually propagated by the service:
>
> - When using the LightStep tracer, Envoy relies on the service to propagate the 
>     [x-ot-span-context](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#config-http-conn-man-headers-x-ot-span-context)
>     HTTP header while sending HTTP requests to other services.
> - When using the Zipkin tracer, Envoy relies on the service to propagate the B3 HTTP headers ( 
>     [x-b3-traceid](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#config-http-conn-man-headers-x-b3-traceid),
>     [x-b3-spanid](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#config-http-conn-man-headers-x-b3-spanid),
>     [x-b3-parentspanid](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#config-http-conn-man-headers-x-b3-parentspanid),
>     [x-b3-sampled](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#config-http-conn-man-headers-x-b3-sampled),
>     and 
>     [x-b3-flags](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#config-http-conn-man-headers-x-b3-flags)).
>     The 
>     [x-b3-sampled](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#config-http-conn-man-headers-x-b3-sampled)
>     header can also be supplied by an external client to either enable or
>     disable tracing for a particular request. In addition, the single 
>     [b3](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#config-http-conn-man-headers-b3)
>     header propagation format is supported, which is a more compressed
>     format.
> - When using the Datadog tracer, Envoy relies on the service to propagate the Datadog-specific HTTP headers ( 
>     [x-datadog-trace-id](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#config-http-conn-man-headers-x-datadog-trace-id),
>     [x-datadog-parent-id](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#config-http-conn-man-headers-x-datadog-parent-id),
>     [x-datadog-sampling-priority](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#config-http-conn-man-headers-x-datadog-sampling-priority)).

---

TLDR: traceId headers need to be manually added to B3 HTTP headers.

Additional information: https://github.com/openzipkin/b3-propagation

Comment: Thanks @piotr-malec

`Whichever tracing provider is being used, the service should propagate the x-request-id to enable logging across the invoked services to be correlated.`

That basically answers my question as I realized by default, envoy/istio-proxy has accessLog that contains the x-request-id value.

Comment: @AgungPratama `x-request-id` may not come into play at all if the services confirm to B3 standards and propagate x-b3-traceId